# Is there a way I can calculate VAT(Value Added Tax = 15%) from gridview columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a code that calculates the total with VAT exclusive and VAT inclusive, the output for total(excl VAT) and total(incl VAT) is correct but I can't get VAT calculation right to add correct amount to total(incl VAT). Before I calculate totals, I firstly need to multiply each price column by quantity column. Here is what I tried:

```
            lblTotalBeforeVat.Text = "0";
            lblVat.Text = "0";
            lblTotalIncludingVat.Text = "0";

            String currency = "ZAR";

            for (int i = 0; i < CartItemsGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //below displays the grand total of the column which is the the total before vat
                lblTotalBeforeVat.Text = Convert.ToString(decimal.Parse(lblTotalBeforeVat.Text) + decimal.Parse(CartItemsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text) * decimal.Parse(CartItemsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text));

                //below calculate the vat
                lblVat.Text = Convert.ToString(decimal.Parse(lblVat.Text) + decimal.Parse(CartItemsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text) * 15 / 100);

                // the below calculates the total including vat
                Label[] arr = new Label[] { lblTotalBeforeVat, lblVat };
                decimal result = 0;
                foreach (var item in arr)
                    result += decimal.Parse(item.Text);
                lblTotalIncludingVat.Text = result.ToString() + currency;

            }
```

Here is the sample output, any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just take `lblVat.Text = Convert.ToString(decimal.Parse(lblTotalBeforeVat.Text) * 0.15);` ? BTW, I'd operate on numbers, only and only in the last step, I'd format to string instead of parse/toString all the time.

Comment: @Fildor I tried that but still give the same output

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the calculation right, I added the following code.

```
decimal quantity = decimal.Parse(CartItemsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[7].Text);

lblVat.Text =  Convert.ToString(decimal.Parse(lblVat.Text) + decimal.Parse(CartItemsGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text) * 15 / 100 * quantity);
```